# Mailbox full error when benchmarking Vapor web framework

Tags: vapor

Running on Mac OS X 10.11 with the example on Vapor site, has anyone getting some error when benchmarking with wrk -c128 -1m http://localhost:8080?

Is those error related to a bug Vapor's code or Swift's performance issue for web development? Can it be fix with high priority.

Testing them from Vapor 0.14-0.16.

Comment: Hey, J, can you clarify what error you're getting? We run all of our benchmarks w/ `wrk`, and I've never seen a mailbox full error. Would love to get this sorted out if we have a bug.

Comment: It works fine for me: `Running 1m test @ http://0.0.0.0:8080
  2 threads and 128 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    10.75ms   22.11ms 393.05ms   97.23%
    Req/Sec     1.21k   541.68     2.72k    66.41%
  143450 requests in 1.00m, 531.52MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 0, write 0, timeout 36
Requests/sec:   2387.47
Transfer/sec:      8.85MB`

Answer (score 0):

Some benchmarking tools, especially when they finish, can improperly handle socket closure. Vapor is overly cautious and prints all socket errors it finds (minus a few very common ones).

Most likely this error is nothing to worry about, especially if the application continues to work normally.

Try running a variety of benchmarking applications and the latest version of Vapor (1.1.12 right now) to see if the problem persists. My guess is that it will go away.